# Is there a Google voice API for making calls using nodejs

Tags: node.js, google-voice, google-voice-actions

Can anyone let me know if there is a google voice api for making calls from nodejs.

an api to specify from number and to number and then it makes the call by itself.

Something similar to this.

[What is the URL to make a Google Voice call using the direct access number?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5526392/what-is-the-url-to-make-a-google-voice-call-using-the-direct-access-number)